# Angular checkbox filter leaves no data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filtering

My checkbox filter is totally removing all data records instead of filtering.
I used this post as guidance: http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/

I can get and console the selected category. I am having problems filtering the list.

My data is like so:

```
{"product_title":"COPD Track Package","product_code":"COPDPKG2014","id":"a1u40000000C182AAC","Id":"a1u40000000C182AAC","sort_order":"6","sort_code":"COPDPKG2014","category":["Postgraduate Course, Continuing Education"]}
```

Here is the angular:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-app="products">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="ShoppingCartCtrl">   
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7"><h3 class="colored-title">Search Filter</h3>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>By Product Title:</td>
<td><input ng-model="search.product_title" type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>By Product Code:</td>
<td><input ng-model="search.product_code" type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>By Presentation Title:</td>
<td><input ng-model="search.presentations" type="text"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>By Speaker Name:</td>
<td><input ng-model="search.speakers" type="text"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeProduct('Postgraduate Course')"/>Postgraduate Course</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-click="includeProduct('Continuing Education')"/>Continuing Education</td>
</tr>
    <tr><td>Filter dump: {{productIncludes}}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table></div>

</div>

<div>Sort by:<select ng-model="sortExpression">
<option value="sort_code">Product Code</option>
<option value="product_title">Product Title</option>
</select></div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
<tr class="warning"><th>Product Code</th><th>Product Title</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:mySortFunction | filter:search |filter:productFilter">
<td valign="top">
{{item.id}}<div ng-repeat="c in item.cat" >{{c}}</div>
</td>
<td>
{{item.product_title}}
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>




$scope.productIncludes = [];

        $scope.includeProduct = function(category){
            var i = $.inArray(category, $scope.productIncludes);
            if(i > -1){
                $scope.productIncludes.splice(i,1);
            }else{
                $scope.productIncludes.push(category);   
            }

            console.log($scope.items.length);
        }


         $scope.productFilter = function (items) {
        if ($scope.productIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(items.cat, $scope.productIncludes) < 0) return;
        }

        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Could you keep only the minimum of that code that reproduces the problem? And could you set up a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is problem with your data representations.

You have categories stored as `"category":["Postgraduate Course, Continuing Education"]` and you want to search in those categories as if it was an array like `"category":["Postgraduate Course", "Continuing Education"]`.

I recommend you to represent your data like the second case and then you can iterate over it like this:

```
$scope.productFilter = function (items) {
  if ($scope.productIncludes.length > 0) {
    var result = $scope.productIncludes.filter(function(n) {
      return items.category.indexOf(n) != -1
    });
    if(result.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
  }
  return items;
}
```

And here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/133/

*Short explanation:*
`filter` function in combination with the `indexOf` function will return an intersection of the two arrays.

Comment: This works perfectly. Still getting used to these wacky looking systax in javascript. thank you!

Comment: If you have any problems, just ask ;)

Comment: Im trying to understand the whole function. is it that for every item, we get the index, which is n? then get the index of the item with the matching category?

Comment: `filter` iterates over given array and passes reference of each array item to the anonymous function as parameter `n`. Anonymous function inside `filter` returns truthy value (boolean) if item is present in the another array. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ok, I am getting it. Built in stuff that just works, like .filter.

Comment: I notice when I clear the 'speakers' input box, the items do not all repopulate. I only get a subset of the items. Could this be because some of the items have no 'speakers', just an empty string?

Comment: jsfiddle works as expected, items repopulate normally